# Missing API Key in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I have a Drupal theme whith a google maps. But the map is missing an api key, and when I open my Drupal page I see this.

[image]

I have a Drupal theme containing a gmap.js file.

Is it possible to change it there.

I tried writing `api=API_KEY;` of course I replaced API_KEY with my own key.

Do anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

It's `key=API_KEY`.
This is an example from Google:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```